# Use mouse scroll anywhere on screen in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, hook

I'm trying to setup global shortcut using mouse button and scrolling combination, (scrolling up (or down) whlie pressing right mouse button).

I'm thinking I should try to react to mouse scroll, but I have no idea how to detect mouse wheel outside of form.

Right now I got it to react to mouse click with timer and setting form to always on top (no prolem with it being always on top), but no idea how to progress with it.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right) = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "YES"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "NO"
    End If

End Sub
```

Goal is to make it minimize aplications set by user with that shortcut, just in case that info is helpful. I have rest of the code just cant figure that part out.

EDIT:
It works inside form with this:

```
Private Sub ListBoxCHOWAJ_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBoxCHOWAJ.MouseWheel

    If MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right) = True Then
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "up"
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = "down"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a mouse hook to detect scrolling outside your application. Have a look at my [InputHelper library](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) and its [low-level mouse hook](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki/Low-level-mouse-hook). You can do all your logic in the `MouseWheel` event handler, no need for the timer any longer.

Comment: Thanks, used as suggested in "low-level mouse hook". And it works just as I wanted. Also you made me learn to add external dll's at last. Though if possible I would rather not use external libraries, if anyone have any ideas...

Comment: Glad my library could be of help! || _"Though if possible I would rather not use external libraries"_ - I understand how you feel, I'm exactly the same :). However there is actually nothing wrong with using external libraries, and my InputHelper library was created for the sole purpose to be used by others and help by simplifying input management (a somewhat complex thing to do in .NET).

Comment: There is a plethora of hook and input simulation implementations for VB.NET/C# out there, but they are almost always incorrect in some way. I created InputHelper to fight all these incorrect implementations with an easy-to-use library that does it correctly and efficiently. :)

Comment: By the way, you should write your solution as an answer instead and mark it as accepted when time allows (unless you want me to write it? :). -- Also, in your code you should remove `WithEvents` and `Handles MouseHook.MouseWheel`. You cannot use both the `AddHandler` solution and the `WithEvents` solution as that causes the events to be raised _twice_. You were meant to choose the solution that suits you the best.

Comment: Deleted AddHandler, since setting handler at sub feels more natural for me. As for answer, go for it if you want, it was your answer afterall, ill upvote if you do.

Comment: An answer is on its way! Though you can't upvote since you have < 15 rep., but you can still mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mouse hook to detect scrolling outside your application. Have a look at my [InputHelper library](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper) and its [low-level mouse hook](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/wiki/Low-level-mouse-hook).

To include it in your project, download the [compiled DLL](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases) and add it as a reference:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Add Reference...`
2. Go to the `Browse` tab.
3. Locate the InputHelper DLL-file, select it and press `OK`.

You can do all your logic in the hook's `MouseWheel` event handler, no need for the timer any longer:

```
Imports InputHelperLib

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents MouseHook As New InputHelper.Hooks.MouseHook

    Private Sub MouseHook_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As InputHelperLib.InputHelper.Hooks.MouseHookEventArgs) Handles MouseHook.MouseWheel
        If MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right) = True Then
            'Do something...
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

There's no need to check `e.Delta` like you did because it will never be 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: @Zabujca : Glad to be of help! Good luck with your project!